# What idempotent command can I use to make a symlink pointing to a directory?

Tags: shell-script, symlink

I want to put a command into a shell script which will create a symlink to directory, but this script could be run over and over, so on subsequent invocations, the command should not change anything.

Here is the directory structure:

```
% tree /tmp/test_symlink 
/tmp/test_symlink
├── foo
└── repo
    └── resources
        └── snippets
            ├── php.snippets
            ├── sh.snippets
            ├── snippets.snippets
            ├── sql.snippets
            └── vim.snippets
```

I want to create a symlink in `foo/` called snippets which points to
the directory `/tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets`.
So I run:

```
% ln -sfv /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets /tmp/test_symlink/foo/snippets
'/tmp/test_symlink/foo/snippets' -> '/tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets'
```

which gives the desired result.

```
% tree /tmp/test_symlink                                                          
/tmp/test_symlink
├── foo
│   └── snippets -> /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets
└── repo
    └── resources
        └── snippets
            ├── php.snippets
            ├── sh.snippets
            ├── snippets.snippets
            ├── sql.snippets
            └── vim.snippets
```

5 directories, 5 files

However, when the command is run again,

```
% ln -sfv /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets /tmp/test_symlink/foo/snippets
'/tmp/test_symlink/foo/snippets/snippets' -> '/tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets'
```

it creates a symlink to a directory, where the symlink aleady exists puts symlink inside the real directory

```
% tree /tmp/test_symlink                                                          
/tmp/test_symlink
├── foo
│   └── snippets -> /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets
└── repo
    └── resources
        └── snippets
            ├── php.snippets
            ├── sh.snippets
            ├── snippets -> /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets
            ├── snippets.snippets
            ├── sql.snippets
            └── vim.snippets
```

why is this happening and how can I modify the command so that subsequent invocations won't create this weird effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the `-T` option for this, it tells `ln` to always treat the link name as the desired link name, never as a directory.

Without this option, if you give `ln` a link name which exists as a directory, it creates a new link to the target inside that directory.

Note that `-T` is a GNU-ism (at least, it’s not in POSIX), but you’re already using `-v` which is a GNU-ism too so I imagine that’s not an issue.

Alternatively, you can just specify the parent directory as the link name, and the link will always be (re-)created there:

```
ln -sfv /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets /tmp/test_symlink/foo/
```

This works because your symlink has the same name as the target.

Comment: thanks, yes the gnu options are not necessarily portable, but they can be really useful - when portability is not a requirement. your answer works for me. From the man page `-n, --no-dereference treat  LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a directory`. `-T, --no-target-directory treat LINK_NAME as a normal file always` do you think it is better to treat a symlink as a file always? I would have thought it would be better to limit the use of these "special" options?

Comment: If you know they’re available, there’s no reason to avoid GNU-specific options (IMO). You asked for an idempotent command, `-T` is how you make `ln` idempotent. There are other ways of getting the same result if you prefer, such as deleting the link and re-creating it, or if you know `foo` exists already, `ln -sfv /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets /tmp/test_symlink/foo/` (actually that might be a better answer altogether, I’ll update).

Comment: cool, yes I had previously been using `if` statements to detect the presence of the symlink and skip the command if the symlink existed, but the scripts end up getting cluttered and hard to read, I was going for something idempotent but simple, like using `mkdir -p` no tests, no logic, just good ol one liners :)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: you mentioned the use of -T, but I couldn't find it in the code snippet of your answer. Am I misunderstanding or missing something?

Comment: @Guizmoo03 perhaps you missed the “Alternatively” which introduces the snippet. The first three paragraphs explain `-T`, but the end of my answer presents another solution which doesn’t use `-T`.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: Oops, you are right :). I really missed the Alternatively. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score -1):

Best I can tell what is happening here is that on the second pass the `ln` command behaves like `cp` or `mv`, which is that if it sees a "directory" at <destination> it will put the file inside it, else if  <destination> doesn't exist, it will make <destination>. (which is what the "slashdot" trick avoids - i.e. it will make sure the <destination> exists and is a directory).
But I could be wrong.

In either case this seems to work

```
ln -sfv --no-dereference /tmp/test_symlink/repo/resources/snippets/ foo/snippets
```