# Can you turn an existing directory into a symlink without directly removing the directory?

Tags: symlink, directory-structure

There is an existing directory, say, `dir`. I want to remove it and create a symlink `dir` to another directory. So I know I can just do `rm -rf dir` and then `ln -s /path/to/that/directory dir`. Is there a way to do it with `ln` without having to `rm`? I didn't see an appropriate help when I did `ln --help`.

Comment: Similar: [What idempotent command can I use to make a symlink pointing to a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/355214)

Comment: Does "without having to `rm`" mean that you do not want to remove the existing directory and it's contents, in which case you could do something like `mv dir dir~`, to keep it as backup. Or does it mean that you just want to do it with one command less?

Answer (score 2):

No such functionality exists.

It's also really sensible that it doesn't: to make that symlink, something of the same name mustn't exist so far. Integrating that deletion functionality into every single program that might create something new makes no sense: Just run `rm`.